# Matrix Exponential: Solve $u''+2u'+u=0$ for $u(0)=u_0, u'(0)=u_1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the problem $u''+2u'+u=0$ for $u(0)=u_0, u'(0)=u_1$ using the matrix exponential.

I first wrote the linear system as $x'_1=x_2$ and $x'_2=-x_1-2x_2$.

I then found $e^{At}= $$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     (t+1)e^{-t} & te^{-t} \\
     -te^{-t} & (1-t)e^{-t}
  \end{array} \right]
$$
$
My book then says that $\vec{x}=e^{A(t-t_0)}x_0$. My question is how do I use this exponential matrix and the initial conditions to find the final answer?

Thanks.

Comment: $$t_0 = 0, x_0 = (u_0, u_1) \implies \vec{x}=e^{A(t)}x_0 = e^{A t}\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
    u_0 \\ u_1
  \end{array} \right]$$

Comment: The question didn't ask for this, but an interesting way to look at this is writing it in the form $(\partial + 1)^2u = 0$. Define $v = (\partial + 1)u = u' + u$, $v(0) = u_0+u_1$, solve $(\partial + 1)v = v' + v = 0$ to get $v(x) = (u_0+u_1)e^{-x}$ and you are left with $u' + u = v$. Homogeneous solution is as before $u_H=u_0e^{-x}$, while particular can be guessed to be $u_P=(u_0+u_1)xe^{-x}$, finally giving $u(x) = (u_0+u_1)xe^{-x}+u_0e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution $x(t)=e^{A(t-t_0)}x_0$ of $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)$ has the initial value $x_0$ for $t=t_0=0$ and $x$ is defined as $x=(x_1,x_2)=(u,u')$. Thus $x_0$ should be defined as $x_0=(u(0),u'(0))=(u_0,u_1)$.